# Forcing <a> tag have the same height as parent <li>

Tags: css

I am designing a top bar for a website and cannot figure out how to force the `<a>` elements below have the same height as the parent `<li>` elements. The code below shows the `<li>` elements with a green background and the `<a>` elements with a yellow background. I would like to have the yellow boxes span the whole height of the green boxes. Setting the height of the `<a>` elements to 100% doesn't do trick. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style>
    div#topbar {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      top: 0;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }   
    #topbar ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      line-height: 30px;
    }
    #topbar ul li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 10px;
      background-color: green;
      display: inline;
      float: left;
    }
    #topbar a {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because  tag is an inline element and it doesn't take height into account so you need make it block which can be made by various methods but most suitable in your case is 'float'.

```
    div#topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}   
#topbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#topbar ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
#topbar a {
  background-color: yellow;
  float:left; /*add this*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YMPe2/

Comment: use display:block too is ok... so all the element is clickable. nice code.

Comment: Is there any difference between using `display: block` and `float: left`?

Comment: Technically, YES-- but in your case no for the time being.

Comment: I would check this in IE6 .. I don't have it on my debugger machine here but it looks good for cross browser and mobile.

Comment: In addition to @TheBlackBenzKid's comment, you can use ```display;flex; justify-content:space-evenly;``` If you happen to be making a sidebar and want the links to slide smoothly with the transition into the side bar

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
#topbar a {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `a` tag should be `display:block`, then it will fill the parent. And lose the padding on the `li` tag.